# Homosexuality in Islam

Tags: homosexuality

I have a question,
so, I know homosexual sex is a great sin in Islam, but is it alright for a man and man to just live together and not do such actions but still love each other? Or is it a sin still?

Comment: It’s still a sin regardless.

Comment: Allah the almighty says: "And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way."[17:32](https://legacy.quran.com/17/32), and zina and homosexual acts are rather alike.

Answer (score 1):

Assalam o allaikum.

(*do correct me if I got this question wrong*)

As per my understanding, you are asking if two people can live together without having any sexual contact and without doing anything that is unlawful in the eyes of Allah.?  If that this the case then why not..

Until or unless if two persons are just living together and taking care of each other, then there is no harm and sin in that.

But, if those two people are really homosexual and also living together, how long do you think that they can actually live, eat, sleep and do everything together without doing anything that is Haram. I hope you get my point brother.